# Hibernate mapped property to SQL formula fails after update to 3.6.5

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have just updated to Hibernate 3.6.5.Final from 3.3.0.GA and have run into a problem with a SQL formula call on an XML mapped property:

```
<property
    name="endDate"
    type="java.util.Date"
    formula="TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, (quantity*60*60), transactionDate)" 
/>
```

I have changed nothing in the *.xml.hbm nor have I changed the database design. Where previously my endDate was nicely calculated I now get a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'this_.SECOND,(this_.quantity*60*60),this_.transactionDate) as formula0_0_ from t' at line 1
```

The problem is pretty obvious in that the `this_.SECOND` should be `SECOND`. It seems to me that Hibernate recognizes the `TIMESTAMPADD` as a formula but not the `SECOND` as a static passed parameter and thinks it thus must be a column in the table. I am unsure how to tell hibernate it should use `SECOND` as is.

I've tried `registerFunction` and `registerKeyword` on my Dialect but without any luck as these seem related to HQL function definitions and not native SQL which is used here in the formula.

Could anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what Hibernate does different between these versions and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same type of problem in Sql Server - a similar solution might work. .

Here is what I found. . 
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2427791

So, try putting quotes around SECOND

```
<property
    name="endDate"
    type="java.util.Date"
    formula="TIMESTAMPADD(&quot;SECOND&quot;, (quantity*60*60), transactionDate)" 
/>
```

I am actually not sure how you would escape double quotes in this xml attribute, but I would try `&quot;` first and if that doesn't work `\"`

Comment: MySQL 5.0 rejects this query: `select TIMESTAMPADD("second", 60, current_date()) =>  You have an error in your SQL syntax near '"second" ...`. Hibernate will note remove the quotes, I believe. Maybe MSSQL is more flexible :)

Comment: I think you got me on the right track here. I did try the double and single quotes which did not work. But [this article][1] suggested using `[SECOND]`. Due to some deadlines on another project I will get back to my hibernate update branch tomorrow and let you know if it worked.


  [1]: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/

Answer (score 3):

I just upgraded to Hibernate 4.1.2 and this same problem started coming back. The solution of [SECOND] no longer works and I had to register the keyword in my own custom Dialect. Like:

```
public class ExtendedMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {

    public ExtendedMySQL5InnoDBDialect() {
        super();
        //make sure to register it in lowercase as uppercase does not work (took me 4 hours to realize)
        registerKeyword("second");

    }
}
```