# hibernate derived properties with xml

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, derived

I have table called Student as Below

```
ID        NAME     DOB
---       ----     ---------
1         A        2009-01-28
2         B        2001-05-20
```

I am using derived properties to get the **AGE** from the dob as below in the hbm file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.arat.derived.Person" table="person" catalog="spring_db">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" />
    </property>
    <property name="dob" type="date">
        <column name="dob" length="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="age" type="integer" column="AGE"
        formula="( select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,p.dob,NOW()) as AGE 
                     from person p where p.ID=ID)"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my POJO class **Student** has all the property id,name,dob and age with setter and getter method.

While fetching the data using load or get method I am getting the error

```
 private static void loadPerson() {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Person person = (Person) session.get(Person.class, 0);
    System.out.println("Person : name " + person.getName() 
            + ", dob: " + person.getDob() + ", age : " + person.getAge());

}
```

> Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_8_0_, person0_.name as name2_8_0_, person0_.dob as dob3_8_0_, ( select TIMESTAMPDIFF(person0_.YEAR,p.dob,NOW()) as person0_.AGE from person p where p.ID=person0_.ID) as formula0_0_ from spring_db.person person0_ where person0_.id=?
>   Feb 07, 2015 7:20:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
>   Feb 07, 2015 7:20:22 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'person0_.YEAR,p.dob,NOW()) as person0_.AGE from person p where p.ID=person0_.ID)' at line 1
>   Feb 07, 2015 7:20:22 PM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad
>   INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSe**

can you tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting issue, related to Hibernate way how to handle `formula=""` SQL snippet.

What happened behind the scene is:

> unexpected injection/extenion of the `formula=""` parts with an TABLE `alias`

That means that this:

```
formula="( select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, NOW()) 
               as AGE from person p where p.ID = ID )"
```

Was converted into that:

```
( select TIMESTAMPDIFF(person0_.YEAR,p.dob,NOW()) 
      as person0_.AGE  from person p where p.ID=person0_.ID)
```

**Firstly** we have to change is the **`as AGE`** which is not needed and is also extended.

```
formula="( select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, NOW()) 
            from person p where p.ID = ID )"
```

**Next** - the alias `person0_` is now used for more parts than we need.

Reason is:

> Hibernate does not know, which parts are
>
> - **native SQL words/keywords** of our DB engine and
> - which are column/property names.

The way how to solve it, is to extend the Dialect, and teach it *new keyword*. E.g. like this

```
// extend the correct dialect ... in thhis case MySql
public class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect
{
    public CustomMySQLDialect()
    {
        super();
        registerKeyword("YEAR");
    }
}
```

And also do not forget to use this new dialect - `CustomMySQLDialect` in configuration

Comment: There is no luck, after creating this custom dialect and adding this dialect in hibernate.cfg.xml file it is throwing the same exceptions.

Comment: Well, it does work for me. Are you sure, you've changed your configuration? That new Custom dialect is now used? If yes, "YEAR" will be the keyword, and will never be "extended" with alias...

Comment: Here I added it:

  `<property       name="hibernate.dialect">com.dialect.CustomMySQLDialect</property>`

Comment: Great job, BUT we also have to adjust the formula  - I updated my answer. I would say that this time your exception was not the same... check the real details... I expect that the problem was with AS AGE

Comment: No luck after removing **as AGE** also.

Comment: As I said, show me the latest exception - as in your original quesiton... need to see what is different. I mean *"Hibernate: select...*

Comment: Below is the exeception Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_8_0_, person0_.name as name2_8_0_, person0_.dob as dob3_8_0_, ( select TIMESTAMPDIFF(person0_.YEAR,p.dob,NOW()) from person p where p.ID=person0_.ID) as formula0_0_ from spring_db.person person0_ where person0_.id=?
Feb 07, 2015 8:40:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Feb 07, 2015 8:40:50 PM s

Comment: did you get the exception?

Comment: Now it is visible. Obviously the keyword was not registered properly, because it is again treated as column name... and extended with alias...

Answer (score 0):

This is a small addition to the Radim Köhler's https://stackoverflow.com/a/28383566/2576551 answer. It seems like the keyword registration in a custom dialect is case sensitive for some hibernate versions. I am running hibernate 4.3.8.Final and keyword has to be lowercase.

```
//doesn't work
registerKeyword("YEAR");

//works
registerKeyword("year");
```

Related thread [Hibernate mapped property to SQL formula fails after update to 3.6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393555/hibernate-mapped-property-to-sql-formula-fails-after-update-to-3-6-5) that proposed to lowercase keyword.