# Use NATURAL JOIN in @Formula in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, formula

I'm having trouble using `NATURAL JOIN` in Hibernate with `@Formula`.

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tz_points_logs` (
  `points_log_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `points_to_uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `points_get_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `points_rule_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `points_meta` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tz_points_rules` (
  `points_rule_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `points_rule_credits` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `points_rule_title` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `points_rule_description` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tz_users` (
  `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In Hibernate, there're three mapping Models: `User`, `PointsLog` and `PointsRule`.

Now, there a `@Formal` field in `User` Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tz_users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    // Getters and Setters

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private long uid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = PointsLog.class, 
                fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<PointsLog> pointsLogs = new ArrayList<PointsLog>();

    @Formula(value = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tz_points_logs pl NATURAL JOIN tz_points_rules WHERE pl.points_to_uid=uid)")
    private long credit;
}
```

There's an error while get credit of the User:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'user0_.NATURAL JOIN tz_points_rules WHERE pl.points_to_uid=user0_.uid) as formul' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems that the Hibernate cannot recognize `NATURAL JOIN` in `@Formula`.
Is there any other method to implement this function?

BTW, following statement works fine.

```
@Formula(value = "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tz_points_logs pl WHERE pl.points_to_uid=uid)")
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28383566/1679310). The point here is - Hibernate treats the `NATURAL` keyword as a property/column name. A workaround should be - register **NATURAL** as a `keyword` in the dialect.

For example:

```
// extend the correct dialect ... in this case MySql
// but simply extend the currently used dialect
public class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect
{
    public CustomMySQLDialect()
    {
        super();
        registerKeyword("NATURAL");
    }
}
```

Next configure Hibernate to be using this `CustomMySQLDialect`, and the FORMULA should be generated:

```
// instead of this
// user0_.NATURAL JOIN

// we should get this
NATURAL JOIN
```

Comment: Still not working `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user0_.NATURAL JOIN tz_points_rules pr WHERE pl.points_to_uid=user0_.uid) as for' at line 1`

Comment: I have add `ExtendedMySQLDialect` class and edited the Spring configuration: In `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`: `hibernate.dialect=com.company.package.database.ExtendedMySQLDialect`

Comment: What you've shown is a proof, that the custom dialect is not in place. Once you will have custome dialect - and configure it in Hibernate configuration .. and register NATURAL keyword, Hibernate will simply NOT use it for injecting 'user_'. I tested, and it is working for me

Comment: Because, what I am trying to say: that is how Hibernate is working. Otherwise it will try to *escape* every word in FORMULAs. But it is not happening. Hibernate knows, what are keywords, which should be skipped...